# Matching two things with string in between

Tags: php, regex, match

I have made a syntax of my own and it works fine for things like this:

```
$str = "abc {{for items}} efg";
preg_match('/(?<={{for )[^}]*(?=}})/', $str, $match);

// Returns: [0] => items
```

But I want to expand the for command to work like this:

```
$str = "abc {{for item in items}} efg";
```

How do I need to modify the regexp to match the "item" and "items" and exclude the "for" and "in" parts?

I am aware that I could do it like this:

```
preg_match('/{{for (.*) in (.*)}}/', $str, $match);
```

But I like my original regexp because it only returns the matched parts so I would like to have some help modifying it to support this example.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
It's not always {{for item in items}} it might aswell be {{for piece in products}} or {{for part in junk}}

Comment: `{{for\s+\K[^\s}]+(?=\s+in\s+[^\s}]+}})|[^\s}]+(?=}})`

Comment: Also forget to add that the syntax is not always "item" in "items". It could be "{{for piece in products}}" too. Bad choice of words in the example for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "only returns the matched parts". In $match you will have all the capture groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your input formats are exactly like above.

```
{{for\s+\K[^\s}]+(?=\s+in\s+[^\s}]+}})|[^\s}]+(?=}})
```

[\K](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match. [`(?=...)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) called positive lookahead assertion.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oC3qA3/1)

Comment: Actually it's not exact, I edited my original post. Sorry for the hassle!

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/oC3qA3/2 it works, if you input is not in the format you mentioned then this would fail. Please add all your test cases.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think you could explain this regexp a bit so I have a chance at getting better myself? What does the \K do?

Comment: @unska see the explanation on the right side of added link.